# multiple select conditions in php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

[i have table like above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zP0p.png)

I want to select and display cost when pickup and droplocation are same as that selected by user from a dropdown having above options.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM location
WHERE Pickup='". $pick. "' ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "You have to pay " . $row['Cost'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

above code will give me 4 options since i haven't checked equality of `dropLocation`.

```
SELECT * FROM location
WHERE Pickup='". $pick. "' AND DropLocation='". $drop. "'  "
```

It is not working. 
How to handle multiple conditions?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `It is not working`?

Comment: i think the $drop is empty or something null

Comment: That second query looks valid and senseful from a technical point of view, that is not the issue. But it smells like a sql attack vulnerability if you concatenate user side input into a query string like that...

Comment: Show us from where `$drop` come and check if is empty. Also this is not how you use `mysqli_*`.

Comment: myPick and myDrop are the name attributes of my dropdown               $pick = isset($_POST['myPick']) ? $_POST['myPick'] : '';
$drop = isset($_POST['myDrop']) ? $_POST['myDrop'] : '';

Comment: @S.I. above code displays cost for all matching values of pickup. It should display only one option corresponding to entered pickup and drop detail

Comment: try my answer @spence8

Comment: thanks a lot @JYoThI it worked!

Comment: if my answer is useful means mark it with green tick its useful to future user reference @spence8

Answer (score 1):

Try this

your code looks have sql attack vulnerability try to use mysqli prepared statement.

```
            <?php

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM location WHERE Pickup=? AND DropLocation=?");

            $stmt->bind_param('ss',$pick,$drop);

            //The argument may be one of four types:

            //i - integer
            //d - double
            //s - string
            //b - BLOB
            //change it by respectively 

            $stmt->execute();

            $get_result =$stmt->get_result();

            $row_count= $get_result->num_rows;

            if($row_count>0)
            {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_result))
                    {
                        echo "You have to pay " . $row['Cost'];
                        echo "<br>";
                    }


            }
             else
             {
                 echo "result set empty";
             }



             $stmt->close();
             $conn->close();

            ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['myPick']) && !isset($_POST['myDrop'])){
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM location
WHERE Pickup='". $pick. "' ");
}else if(!isset($_POST['myDrop']) && isset($_POST['myPick'])){
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM location
WHERE DropLocation='". $drop. "' ");
}else if(isset($_POST['myDrop']) && isset($_POST['myPick'])){
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM location
WHERE Pickup='". $pick. "' AND DropLocation='". $drop. "' ");
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "You have to pay " . $row['Cost'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```